# Handle embedded browser 404 error from external DLL in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am integrating a legacy system and have to access it's API by invoking a DLL. At the moment, there is no other way to call the API.

And the problem is that DLL shows tries to display a splash screen which throws a file not found error.

I was able to replicate this behaviour in a sample solution, even though it's more a guess, since I DotPeek couldn't decompile the API's DLL.

Solution.

[image]

Error message.

[image]

Application code.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var dll = Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "WpfLibrary.dll"));
        var type = dll.GetType("WpfLibrary.TestWindow");
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        object[] parameters = { };
        instance.GetType().InvokeMember("Start2", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, parameters);
    }
}
```

DLL code.

```
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Start2()
    {
        Show();
        WebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("file:///C:/aaaa.txt"));
    }
}
```

A simple work around is to create the missing file, however I can't create files on every machine the WPF application will be installed, need a better solution.

My question is how can I handle/catch such errors coming from an external DLL? It would suffice if I could prevent error message box from being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would to put your code in a try catch clause.

```
try
{
    var dll = Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "WpfLibrary.dll"));
    var type = dll.GetType("WpfLibrary.TestWindow");
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    object[] parameters = { };
    instance.GetType().InvokeMember("Start2", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, instance, parameters);
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    //handle exception
}
```

/edit
You could try this codesnippet

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomainUnhandledException);
```

Comment: Doesn't work. WebBrowser control doesn't throw any exceptions in my case.

Comment: Hmmm, ok. And you don't want to or can check if the file exists and throw an exception in your dll I guess.

Comment: I would like to, however I do not have control over that DLL at all... Just received a compiled binary...

Comment: Interesting idea! `Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode` doesn't work in WPF. I've also tried `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException` and none of them catch any exceptions.. Seems like WebBrowser control doesn't treat 404 as an exception..